# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA() different results from Excel{}?

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets

I'm getting some odd results when using an ARRAYFORMULA() function in Google Sheets. Comparing the same formula in Excel, I get a correct answer in Excel and an incorrect answer in Google Sheets.

[Here is a shared Google Sheet with the error and a screenshot of the result from Excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8i7lT5ksyDJ8nGzVMv7gQENvITtxaWtUzsJ2Ots_NQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The result should be 12, meaning that there are 12 months where Bob works in at least one location.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google sheets has a lot of different functions.  Use this instead:

```
=count(UNIQUE(filter(A2:A22,B2:B22=E4)))
```

Comment: So, this is a much simplified version of the actual platform, and I haven't been able to get Count/Unique/filter to work correctly.

This works correctly but is very resource intensive: 

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(Metrics!$H2:H<>"",IF(Metrics!$H2:H=AT3,MATCH(Metrics!H2:$H&Metrics!C2:$C,Metrics!H2:$H&Metrics!C2:$C,0))),ROW(Metrics!$H2:H)-ROW(Metrics!$H2)+1)>0)))`

Comment: Then you should have given the full picture and not just a smaller version.  This answered this question.  If you cannot make this work ask a new question with the full breadth of the problem.  We can only answer what is asked. @Gondi

Comment: From the looks of it it should be `FILTER(C:C,H:H = AT3)`

Comment: I do appreciate the help, but to your comment, my post was specifically focused on why Google Sheets would give a different answer than the same function in Excel, and not "Solve my problem for me" that's why I didn't give the full scope of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that filter does accomplish the goal, although I'm still curious why the arrayformula function would be giving a different result.

Comment: The answer is that Google sheets does not iterate, even with ArrayFormula, countifs.  The only way around is to use the formulas that are specifically made to do what you want.  The code behind the formulas are different and since Google has other methods never incorporated the abillity to use them in array formulas.

Comment: Great, that's good to know for the future. Thanks again for the help.